# How auto redirect in HttpClient in Java

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

In the network I am in every new browser session gets authenticated automatically, which takes about 10 seconds and two redirects (I think Javascript). How can I set HttpClient to follow those redirections?

This didn't work:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("172.125.166.5", 8080, "http");
            DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
```

Comment: Ever heard of sendRedirect

Comment: possible duplicate of [How auto redirect in HttpClient (java, apache)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840707/how-auto-redirect-in-httpclient-java-apache)

Comment: How does senRedirect help here?? No, its not a a 301/302 redirection

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the responses and extract redirection URLs and execute new requests with these URLs. However this will not be enough for authentication, which uses some more sophisticated authentication method (which can require browser plugin or SSL certificate).